# Insert method produces error on attempt of adding binary code in Python

Tags: python, list

While I try adding binary code to the list using insert() method I got following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position
> 0: invalid start byte

With append() method this works just fine.

```
for c in range(len(nlist)):
    #print(nlist[c])
    with open (nlist[c], 'rb') as chunk:
        header=chunk.read(1024)
    #nlist.insert(c*2+1, header)
    nlist.append(header)
```

Comment: what is your `nlist` ?

Comment: it's a set of file paths: ['E:\\foto\\IMG 1873(2).jpg', 'E:\\foto\\IMG 1873.jpg'] etc

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with append as I couldn't move forward with insert, had to create nested list first (nlist elements in tohash list).

```
for c in range(len(tohash)):
    with open (tohash[c][0], "rb") as chunk:
        header=chunk.read(1024)
    tohash[c].append(header)
```